# How can i get the lowest price and correspond shop of that price in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Thank you for reading my question. I am doing an Excel for myself. But i am not flexible enough.

May I know how can I get the correspond `Column(shop name)`, when I get the Lowest price in another row?

In this sheet, `G2` to `S2` are the shop name

in the lowestprice column I used `=min (to find out ShopA to ShopB's lowest price)`

May i know how can i get the correspond Shop name that appear in `E3` in this case? it should be `ShopA`  (and how about if two shop have a same lowest price?)

May i know how can i get the Column that showed the ShopA result? (Sorry for i typed wrong `which row`).  For example, The lowest price of `ItemNo:70310` is `HK$3`, `D3` shows `$3`, `E3` shows `shopA`, and how can I make `F3` to show `G`?

thank you very much! I hope i could learn this experience.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX($G$2:$S$2,MATCH(D3,$G3:$S3,0))
```